# Python async doesn't see Google Cloud Firestore in emulator

Tags: python, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I tried the following Cloud functions:

```py
    @https_fn.on_request()
    def updateReports_sync(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
        db = firestore.client()
        doc_ref = db.collection("sync").document("alovelace")
        doc_ref.set({"first": "Ada", "last": "Lovelace", "born": 1815})
        return https_fn.Response("OK")
    
    
    @https_fn.on_request()
    def updateReports_async(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
        db: google.cloud.firestore.AsyncClient = AsyncClient()
        # db = firestore_async.client()
        doc_ref = db.collection("async").document("alovelace")
    
        async def iterateClients():
            await doc_ref.set({"first": "Ada", "last": "Lovelace", "born": 1815})
    
        asyncio.run(iterateClients())
        return https_fn.Response("OK")
```

Async function doesn't work with Emulator (though it works when deployed). No errors reported, but doesn't write to the database. Similar sync function works on Emulator.

Why is it?